# level editor's tiles don't change when I hold the mouse down?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse

Can someone tell me why my level editor's tiles don't change when I hold the mouse down? Full source: http://pastebin.com/U3KKSRT8

```
private void MapPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            map.tiles[(int)(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X / map.tileSize)][(int)(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y / map.tileSize)] = 1;
            MapPanel.Refresh();
        }
```

And this is where the map is drawn.

```
 private void MapPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            for (int i = 0; i < map.tiles.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < map.tiles[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle((i * map.tileSize) - hScrollValue, (j * map.tileSize) - vScrollValue, 30, 30);
                    g.DrawImage(tileMap, destRect, (map.tiles[i][j] * 50), 0, 50, 50, units);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The way you draw the tiles doesn't make much sense.  You only seem to change the srcX argument for DrawImage() when it is clicked.  What do you expect to happen, what actually does happen?

Comment: @Hans Passant, I suspect that the sprite sheet is one long image so each subsequent tile is only offset in the X direction, which would then make sense as to why only the srcX is changing.

Comment: Nah, I just hadn't coded it in yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that the index into the `map.tiles` array is calculating to an expected value? I think that `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` is giving you screen coordinates and you probably want to work with client coordinates of `MapPanel`. Have your tried using X,Y properties of the `MouseEventArgs` class in your calculation?

I took a quick look at your code and you will also need to factor the scroll position into that calculation of the index. I say this based on the fact that your `Paint` routine is offsetting the rendered cells based on the scroll position.

Comment: MouseEventArgs worked, and I'll keep the scrolling in mind. ty